# Samsung Apps for Galaxy S4 with CyanogenMod

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung-apps

I am going to change the official stock Android on my Samsung Galaxy S4 to the latest version of CyanogenMod. But after reading some forum threads about how beautiful and useful it is, I have a question regarding Samsung Apps:

Is there any Samsung Apps available or is it possible to install them somehow?

The problem is that I do not really want to lose my camera functionality (double camera photo and automatic color correction), hover function, S Memo, Samsung Apps, S Planner and so on.

What you may suggest me? I really liked that CM functionality, but I also need almost all of the Samsung default tools, like S Memo (the most useful for me).

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not be able to use your Samsung application for camera. You will you the cyanogen mod one or any other variant that you can find on the market.

As a side note Cyanogen mod is working on their own camera that it suposed to be very good, but at this moment it is in very early beta stage, so who knows when will they actually realease that.